# jQuery how to get number from string?

Tags: jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<span class="price-old" style="padding: 2px;">179,00 DKK</span>
```

or it could be:

```
<span class="price-old" style="padding: 2px;">1.750,00 DKK</span>
```

How do I get the number?

Comment: Your number itself is formatted incorrectly, do you mean 179.00 or 1,750.00?

Comment: @smerny It's formatted in European style.

Comment: My solution: `alert($('.price-old').text().split(',')[0].replace('.', '' ));` http://jsfiddle.net/UUeZM/10/

Comment: @Railsbeginner that will ignore the numbers after the decimal point.

Comment: @dave - They are unnecessaryin my case, they just always eqal 00

Comment: @Railsbeginner In that case only use that if you are sure (really, really sure) that they will always be `00` *forever*. Otherwise when you add a `100,99` value in 8 months you'll be left wondering why everything's suddenly broken.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
parseInt($('.price-old').text().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ""));  //<-- Remove parseInt() to include value after decimal point
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cdFtM/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gaZcn/5/)**

```
 parseInt($('.price-old').text().replace(',', '').replace('DKK', ''))
```

Comment: I still get the DKK, I want to parse the string as a integer.

Comment: `alert($('.price-old').text().split(',')[0]);`

Comment: You have to split on space.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var value=$('.price-old').val();
value=value.split(' ')[0];
alert(val);//just for check
```

Comment: You also need to fix the european formatting. e.g. `1,99` (which won't parse to a number correctly)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove DKK and swap spaces with commas. `replace` will help you:

```
+$('.price-old').text().replace( /[^0-9,]/g, '' ).replace( ',', '.' );
```

(the `+` at the start converts it into a number)

The `.` / `,` swapping is necessary because JavaScript parses numbers in English form; `.` is the decimal point, `,` is a group separator.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
parseInt($('.price-old').text().replace(/[^\d]/g, ''), 10)
```

Where:

`$('.price-old').text().replace(/[^\d]/g, '')` is for stripping off all non-numeric characters from the text

`parseInt(string, 10)` is for converting to numeric on base 10.

You can also do the same with:

`Number($('.price-old').text().replace(/[^\d]/g, ''))`